# Why do say (How + clause!)?

Tags: interjections

I was reading a novel entitled Narnia: The magician's nephew and came across this:

> “I bet she was a bad fairy,” thought Digory; and added out loud, “But
> what about Polly?”
>
> “**How you do harp on that!**” said Uncle Andrew.

I've known the meaning of the phrasal verb *harp on* i.e. to talk or complain about something many times. However, Uncle Andrew didn't reverse the verb and the subject and it has no question mark, what was the author trying to illustrate? Did Uncle Andrew use an interjection? I haven't seen [How + clause!] like that before. But I have seen something like:

> How slowly you walk!
>
> How sweet these grapes are!

Exactly, what I'm familiar with is the usage of

> How + adjective/adverb + clause!

One example I took from Swan's book (*Oxford Grammar)* that I can't say [How + clause] e.g.

> How this is difficult!

Instead, Swan suggests saying:

> How difficult this is!

Comment: Uncle Andrew's exclamation is relatively "literary, poetic, erudite", especially today. To the extent that it occurs at all today, it wouldn't normally include initial ***how*** anyway, but it's worth noting that the primary reason for using this construction at all is so the speaker can place heavy stress on the auxiliary verb ***do*** for emphasis. But because it sounds a bit "florid" (especially with initial ***How***), if Uncle Andrew were a real person speaking today, he might say *You **always** harp on about that!* or ***I wish you wouldn't** harp on about that* to convey exasperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special rule going on here. This is simply one of the ways the word **how** can be used, as the dictionary will tell you:

> [**how**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how#Adverb), adverb
> 4. *Used as a modifier to indicate surprise, delight, or other strong feelings in an exclamation.*
> ***How** very interesting!*
> ***How** wonderful it was to receive your invitation.*

Swan is correct that it is always used with *inversion*, that is, the adjective or adverb comes after "how" and before the verb.

Comment: How you sing nicely! How you **do** sing nicely! (stronger)

Comment: More idiomatically in the real world today (as opposed to the world of Victorian literary fiction), *How nicely you sing!* (or *You **do** sing nicely!*)